# Trying to Launch Google App Engine, given error related to python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

[image]

I have installed python and don't really know what this means. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try opening launcher preferences (what it refers to in the last line), and tell it where you installed Python. There should be a "Python path" setting that you can set.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the python.exe in your `PATH`.
2. **OR** When you open and run cmd.exe, go to your python installation, which will be `C:\Python26\` and from there execute python.exe `PATH_TO_YOUR_APPENGINE_SDK\dev_server.py YOUR_APP`